# Pandas, Python - How to export data frame as csv within a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

```
import json
from glom import glom
import pandas as pd

#selected data, tables assembly, and export as csv.

def table():

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(1,10):
        with open(f'{pathway}\calls_{i}.json','r') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)

            specsA=('PreviousDraws',['DrawNumber'])
            draw=((glom(data,specsA)))#list type
            df['DrawNumbers'] = draw
        
            for j in range(0,5):
                specsB=('PreviousDraws',['WinningNumbers'],[f'{j}'],['Number'])
                number=(glom(data,specsB)) #list type
                df[f'Index{j}'] = number

       return df.to_csv("file1-9.csv", index=False)
       #print(df) 

table()
```

Result without exporting to csv:

[image]

From the code above, without exporting csv yet, it successfully shows all nine tables fully assembled in a single run. However, when I tried to export them into csv, only the first table is exported, but not the rest. How can all nine tables within a loop be exported? I had tried moving the indentation, but it wouldn't work. I had also put a new loop, but that would complicate the run.

Comment: Don't `return`, just save `df` to a new csv file on each iteration. Perhaps `df.to_csv(f"file_{i}.csv")` within the loop?

Comment: @not_speshal, Thanks. that work! hahaha. I had something similar, but was getting errors. I didn't know that I can approach it without return nor print.